# Android Mobile Apps query from the azure database returns last row only

Tags: azure-mobile-services

There's more than 15 items in my azure database table called Events.

I've tried to run most of the commands found on
    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-android-how-to-use-client-library such as :

```
List<Events> results = eventsTable.execute().get()
```

and

```
List<Events> results = eventsTable.select("Events").execute().get();
```

and

```
List<Events> results = eventsTable.top(20).execute().get();
```

to return all the row items in the table. The queries seem to run on the last row of the table **only** and returns the last row or nothing at all when query is executed.

Though the ToDoItem Quickstart from Azure works perfectly with all the queries - which is odd.

Here's some of the code

```
ArrayList<Events> events = new ArrayLists<Events>();

private void EventsFromTable() {

    AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>(){
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            try {
                final List<Events> results = EventsTable.execute().get();

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        for (Events event : results) {
                            Events ev = new Events(event.getName(), event.getVenue(), event.getDate());
                            events.add(ev);
                            System.out.println("size is " +events.size());
                            <======This returns "size is 1"======>
                        }
                    }
                });
            } catch (final Exception e){
                createAndShowDialogFromTask(e, "Error");
            }

            return null;
        }

    };
    runAsyncTask(task);
}
```

Might any one know what the matter is?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your code, the variable `events` seems to be a public shared instance of `ArraryList` in your Android app, so I don't know whether exists the case which multiple threads access it concurrently. The implementation of `ArrayList` class is not synchronized, please see [here](https://developer.android.google.cn/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html).

So please use the code below instead of the code `ArrayList<Events> events = new ArrayLists<Events>();` when you shared the variable between UI thread and data async task thread.

```
List<Events> events = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayLists<Events>());
```

And I think it's better for copying data retrieved from table via `addAll` method, not `add` method for each, as the code below.

```
@Override
public void run() {
    events.addAll(results);
}
```